Routing between 2 interfaces on a host
I seem to be having trouble reaching an application that is running on the 2nd interface on my Ubuntu workstation.
Kernel/OS
Linux 6.5.0-18-generic #18~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Feb  7 11:40:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
I have 2 applications running, 1 application per interface on port 80. The 1st interface which is the default, is running gitlab with embedded nginx webserver enabled. The second interface, I have a mediawiki application launched through docker-compose that explicitly binds itself to the host by the static IP address of the 2nd interface.
Both interfaces are on the same network:
1st Interface: 10.9.205.9
2nd Interface: 10.9.205.10
I've set a url to reach the wiki within it's global ".php" file which works by typing in the specified URL in the web browser. All computers on the network can reach the wiki, but when on the workstation locally it returns "Connection timed out"
Locally from the workstation, i've tried to cURL the url prepended with the http protocol like so:
curl http://example.wiki.local -vvv
The above command returns "No route to host" after waiting for about a minute or 2.
I've ran wireshark on the 2nd interface, and for filters i'm checking tcp traffic on port 80 going to the static IPv4 of the second interface. Doing so I'm able to see traffic coming in from other workstations going to the wiki, but restarting wireshark and trying to reach the wiki locally no traffic gets captured.
This issue seems to indicate some routing statements that need to get defined, so I tried doing this:
sudo ip route add 10.9.205.10/32 via 10.9.205.9
(".10" being the IP address of the second interface, ".9" being the 1st interface IP.)
I'm still unable to get to the wiki locally. What is needed to get my setup working?
NOTE: If the return of any command is needed, I'll be able to provide to the best of my ability

Try setting
net.ipv4.ip_forward to 1 to enable ip forwarding (also check firewall, maybe that is blocking it):
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

I enabled IP forwarding on the system by editing "/etc/sysctl.conf/" directly. net.ipv4.ip_forward now has a value of 1. Also for testing purposes the firewall is currently disabled. Still unable to curl content on the 2nd interface

Can you curl based on the 2nd IP address (curl 10.9.205.10)? Or first, can you ping the 2nd IP address?

Using curl on the 2nd IP address (no port specified) returns me a 404 page from gitlab
Using curl on the 2nd IP address w/ port 8080 specified (port used for app) returns me this:

Trying 10.9.205.19:8080...
connect to 10.9.205.10 port 8080 failed: No route to host
Failed to connect to 10.9.205.10 port 8080 after 4098 ms: No route to host
Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.9.205.10 port 8080 after 4098 ms: No route to host

ping is able to communicate to the 2nd ip address
